# Textblock binding with hyperlink

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a textblock, i want to bind it to a text with a hyperlink.

What i have now:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" xml:space="preserve"> To view the window click <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ShowWindow, ElementName=ThisDialog}">here</Hyperlink>.
```

What i'm trying to achieve:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=TextWithHyperlink}" .../>
```

This way i can keep the content of my text within my viewmodel, but is this possible? if yes how should i do it?

Comment: What is the contents of: TextWithHyperlink?

Comment: "To view the window click here", i want the word "here" to be hyperlinked

Comment: How are you planning to embed the link in your string property? Or is your TextWithHyperlink property of type Run?

Comment: thats what i want to know, is it possible to embed the link in my string?

Comment: The `Inlines` property of the TextBlock may contain [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) instances. Unfortunately, you can't bind `Inlines` as it is a read-only property. You may however add Inline elements in code-behind.

Comment: Yeah, @Lynct, I was thinking that you could use a converter for that. You would need a way to denote the link in plain string though. Maybe with a <a> tag or something, it all depends on how your TextWithHyperlink property is formatted.